# C#, SQL, знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sql-server

**Доброго времени суток,пишу десктопное приложение на c# (wpf), использую сервер на Microsoft Azure.**
При передачи строки varchar, на сервер приходят знаки вопроса, но только в отдельном столбце.
Строка подключения (первоначальный коннект, без доп свойств):

```
 SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server = **; Database = **; User Id = **; Password = ***;");
```

Comment: *При передачи строки varchar, на сервер приходят знаки вопроса, но только в отдельном столбце.* Поясни - причём не только подробно, но и абсолютно точно. (1) Что значит "в отдельном столбце"? Когда отправляется строго один столбец? Всегда один (какой-то? или определённый по независимому критерию, скажем, первый в списке) из всех отправленных? Один определённый, если отправлен? что-то ещё? (2) Как определил, что "на сервер **приходят** знаки вопроса"? Сниффил трафик? Читал логи? Если имеется в виду, что после сохранения в таблицу обратно из неё достаются вопросики - то это совсем не "приходят".

Comment: Только начинаю изучать тему баз данных и тд. Пример: 5 столбцов, все varchar, и только 1 из столбцов вместо строки сохраняет вопросы.

Comment: На SQL Server обычно такая фигня наблюдается, если забыто `N`. То есть VARCHAR вместо **N**VARCHAR в структуре, или 'строка' вместо **N**'строка' в тексте запроса...

Comment: *вместо строки сохраняет вопросы* Почему? Может, сохраняет нормально, а при обратном доставании портится... скажи, что невозможно?

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло :)
Изменил с varchar`a на nvarchar.